# Return URL not working in link

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, webforms

I am using ASP.net and having problems redirecting the the original requested URL after login. The URL is showing clearly in the address bar but when signing it it takes me to Default.aspx every time:

```
http://development-4/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fControls%2fFinancial%2fAddressBook.aspx
```

Comment: How are you doing this redirect?

Comment: It seems to just do it after the session has expired depending on the page you requested.

Comment: How are you redirecting?  FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("userName", isPersistant);

Comment: It's just Response.Redirect

Answer (score 1):

The .NET framework already handles automatically redirecting using the 'ReturnUrl' value.  Unless you're taking the user somewhere other than they attempted to go, use the following to redirect them to their requested page.

Replace 'userName' with the username they provided while logging in.  'isPersistant' refers to whether the cookie should persist browser sessions or be deleted when their window is closed.

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("userName", isPersistant);
```

If you have chosen to take the user somewhere else, your code should look similar to this.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("userName", isPersistant);
Response.Redirect("~/SomePage.aspx");
```

Because you didn't provide very much background information, I'll add the following config.  you should have something similar.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="loginCookieName" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="60" path="/" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="login.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```